# Error message while building a docker image "Error processing tar file(exit status 1)"

Tags: python, linux, bash, docker

**Dockerfile :**

```
FROM centos:6.7

RUN yum -y groupinstall 'Development Tools'

RUN mkdir /compose-portal

ADD roche-ui /compose-portal/roche-ui

ADD http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tar.xz /compose-portal/

WORKDIR "/compose-portal/Python-2.7.6"

ADD . ./configure

WORKDIR "/compose-portal"

RUN curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | bash -

RUN yum -y install nodejs

WORKDIR "/compose-portal/roche-ui"

RUN npm install; npm install -g bower; bower --allow-root install; exit 0

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT npm start
```

*Got following error:*

> Error message while building a docker image "Error processing tar file(exit status 1): Error setting up pivot dir: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay/58a0a77992c4abd3328a5a6ee62abd5c5dedcb1a06858e829beed6c707a08634/merged/compose-portal/Python-2.7.6/configure/.pivot_root902123111: not a directory"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you `ADD` a remote tar file, and try to decompress as directory automatically in 

`ADD http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tar.xz /compose-portal/`

but docker will not decompress tar from remote address automatically.

> If  is a local tar archive in a recognized compression format (identity, gzip, bzip2 or xz) then it is unpacked as a directory. Resources from remote URLs are **not** decompressed. When a directory is copied or unpacked, it has the same behavior as tar -x, the result is the union of:

from: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add

maybe you should decompress it manually.